# What to use on Windows Server 2008 since NETDIAG isn't supported?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller, windows

I need to troubleshoot some DNS issues on a Windows 2008 domain controller, but I see that NETDIAG isn't supplied or supported anymore. I could just copy it from a Server 2003 DC, but it looks like the output wouldn't be reliable. Everywhere I look online, people quickly say "It's not supported anymore" without giving a replacement for the functionality.

What can I use to do the same type of DNS/network diagnostics since I can't use NETDIAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the relevant tests that were part of netdiag were moved to other diagnostics components.  I know dcdiag does a set of DNS tests specific to necessary functionality on domain controllers.  Other tools like ping, nslookup, ipconfig, etc. may help with the other things netdiag did in its all encompassing diagnostics check.

We had some DNS issues recently, and were able to resolve them by simply using dcdiag and the other commands mentioned above.